# Lua/Torch reshape table

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table, torch

I have loaded a `200x200` rgb image and have passed it through a neural network by reshaping it into a `1x(200x200x3)` vector using

```
img1=torch.reshape(img,1,image_size*image_size*3)
```

The output I am getting is also a `1x(200x200x3)` vector. How can I reshape it into an rgb image of size `200x200` so that I can print it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the function `permute(x, y, z)` to change the image to the shape 3x200x200, then you should be able to print it using `itorch.image(your_image)`.The letters `x, y, z` are the index of the columns in your Tensor. Here you have an example.

```
x = torch.Tensor(3,4,2,5)
> x:size()
 3
 4
 2
 5
[torch.LongStorage of size 4]

y = x:permute(2,3,1,4) -- equivalent to y = x:transpose(1,3):transpose(1,2)
> y:size()
 4
 2
 3
 5
[torch.LongStorage of size 4]
```

After this step just do the same as you did. Let's say our img_size is 5.

```
th> t = torch.Tensor(5,5,3)


[0.0001s]   
th> t = t:permute(3,1,2)
                                                                          [0.0001s] 
th> t:size()
 3
 5
 5
[torch.LongStorage of size 3]
                                                                      [0.0001s] 
th> t[{2}]:fill(2)
 2  2  2  2  2
 2  2  2  2  2
 2  2  2  2  2
 2  2  2  2  2
 2  2  2  2  2
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 5x5]

                                                                      [0.0003s] 
th> t[{3}]:fill(3)
 3  3  3  3  3
 3  3  3  3  3
 3  3  3  3  3
 3  3  3  3  3
 3  3  3  3  3
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 5x5]

                                                                      [0.0004s] 
th> w = t:reshape(1,t:size(2)*t:size(3)*3)
                                                                      [0.0001s] 
th> w
Columns 1 to 26
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2

Columns 27 to 52
 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3

Columns 53 to 75
 3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1x75]

th> x = w:reshape(3,5,5)
                                                                      [0.0001s] 
th> x
(1,.,.) = 
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0

(2,.,.) = 
  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2

(3,.,.) = 
  3  3  3  3  3
  3  3  3  3  3
  3  3  3  3  3
  3  3  3  3  3
  3  3  3  3  3
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 3x5x5]
```

Comment: The column vector has 3x200x200=120,000 entries. The first 3 values are the rgb values for the first pixel, the second 3 values are the rgb values for the second pixel and so on. I need no reshape this into a 200x200 matrix of 3 tuples. How can I do this?

Comment: @Sibi in this case, the output can be changed to the image in this way: from column 1 to column 200*200 is the first channel of image, from column 200*200 +1 to column 2*200*200 is the second channel, and from 2*200*200+1 to the end (3*200*200) is the third channel. I will edit the answer so it will be easier to see.